# Is there evidence for the claims made in Opinion Global's article about Salvador Allende Gossens's regime in Chile

Tags: chile

###### Introduction

The article   [Allende, asesinatos y violencia para imponer el socialismo a sangre y fuego](https://www.opinionglobal.cl/allende-asesinatos-y-violencia-para-imponer-el-socialismo-a-sangre-y-fuego/) (Meaning " Allende, assassinations and violence to impose socialism by blood and fire" in spanish) by the Chilean newsletter Opinion Global does have the following claims:

1. As first Salvador Allende Gossens Government did pardon several terrorists of MIR, and he did justify that action with the claim that these young people were "idealists" who had mistaken the way to implement solidarity in the society in which they lived. [The pardon is backed by Nieva (2014), but no the claim by Salvador Allende Gossens]
2. As second Salvador Allende Gossens disbanded the Carabineros Mobile Group, in charge of controlling and fighting violent extremist groups and responsible for the imprisonment of many of the terrorists pardoned shortly before.
3. The non-existence of right-wing paramilitary groups before Salvador Allende Gossens's government.
4. The government of Salvador Allende Gossens did cooperate (at lest by no persecuting the aggressor) with the far-left terrorist group MIR for the violent occupation of farms in the country. [Somewhat implied by Nieva (2014) & CASTILLO VICENCIO (2007)]
5. "The crimes committed during the violent occupations of farms were also very important. Most of them were committed by the Revolutionary Peasant Movement, a franchise of the MIR in the rural world. In this series of events, which were committed in many cases by members of the Socialist Party, the main political force of the government coalition, there are dramatic events. Perhaps the most shocking of all was that committed against Antonia Maechell Ricardi, owner of La Tregua de Valdivia. This middle-aged woman was kidnapped in her own home, raped and abducted. A situation that led to her suicide." - Opinion Global, article in discussion. [Somewhat implied by Nieva (2014)]
6. In a commentary is claimed that the paramilitary right-wing groups were created after Allende government inauguration for self-defense. [Somewhat implied by a foot note in de Los Angeles Crummett (1977)]

Although there are no all the claims made in the article, these affirmations are the ones I am interested with the purpose of research.

###### Previous research

With my research so far I consider prudent give the following observations:

1. The claim number 2 would be somewhat implied by the inaction implied by the 4 & 5 claim (given that 4 & 5 are true) as said in Cámara de Diputados de Chile (1973), he did destroy the rule of the law, so there is more to think that he at last obstructed their capacity to operate. ("Cámara de Diputados de Chile" roughly means "Senate of Chile" in spanish)
2. I was unable to find any evidence that give any relevant backing to the claim number 3, literally my search give no information about this.
3. I was unable to find minimal information about claim number 6 in general, with most of the search results speaking either about Pinochet's relation with the groups, mentions of these groups in very general essays about the situation in Chile in the epoch, but no mention of specific actions by the groups neither declarations by the members, although de Los Angeles Crummett (1977) suggest that in a footnote.

###### The question

Are there primary sources refuting or supporting these claims about Allende's regime in Chile?

###### Important notes

- I may be too notice to research, and I have any kind of training about historical research.
- About the claim  number 6, this claim is somewhat politicized by nature of political wing and self-defense, therefore refrain to do more than cite the primary sources (referring to the claims of the founder members of the groups), if you think that there is some actions taken by the groups that refute those claims list it as a plausible proof with the proper references without saying it is false or true.

###### APA References:

Cámara de Diputados de Chile. (1973, August). *ACUERDO ADOPTADO POR LA N. CÁMARA DE DIPUTADOS, EL DÍA 23 DE AGOSTO DE 1973, Y DIRIGIDO A S. E. EL PRESIDENTE DE LA REPÚBLICA*. Internet Archive. https://archive.org/details/mj-00061-acuerdo-1973-8-23

CASTILLO VICENCIO, A. (2007). *La verdad olvidada del terrorismo en Chile, 1968–1996*. Editorial Maye Ltda.

de Los Angeles Crummett, M. (1977). El Poder Feminino: the Mobilization of Women Against Socialism in Chile. Latin American Perspectives, 4(4), 103–113. https://doi.org/10.1177/0094582x7700400407

Nieva, J. D. (2014). *En torno a la erosión del estado de Derecho: las primeras medidas del gobierno de Salvador Allende: entre el miedo y la polémica*. *Revista Derecho Público Iberoamericano*, 173–208. https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/articulo?codigo=5635447

Comment: *"Are there primary sources refuting or denying these claims..."* -> Do you mean *"...refuting or supporting..."* ?

Comment: The purpose of this "question" seems to be to pair uncontested historical claims with highly contentious characterizations, unfalsifiable since they are essentially opinion-- so essentially propaganda.

Comment: First of all what are that supposed "contentious characterizations", Secondly "contentious characterizations" does no mean opinion, and last this is a question, I am doing a essay about Chile History, and this are of relevancy about it.

Comment: @antlersoft Not a specialist of the history of Chile, could you detail which part are historical claims and which parts are characterizations in OP's question?

Comment: @totalMongot Te same I queestions me?

Comment: @ErdelvonMises Yes I did not see yourcomment when I wrote mine